# Bash checking for foldername using substring

Tags: bash, grep, directory, ls

I need some help with a bash script.

The script should work in a "database-ish" style.

I need to

- add customers, which will be given a customer-number
- create a folder for each new customer (if I run the program from directory 
  /company/myprogram each new customer will have **his own folder** within that directory)

When I start the program, I want it to ask me for a customer-number.

If a customer is new, program will ask for his credentials and after providing them, a customer will be made by making a new folder named "'customer-number' 'surname'" i.e. *15112101 Doe*.

If a customer already exists, it should display a message "customer already exists" and go to said customer.

Now here's the catch. I already tried using things like 
string="15112101"

```
if [[ ! -d "$string" ]]; then
 echo "No such customer"
else 
 cd "$string"
```

But how can I determine whether current directory contains a folder **starting** with this customer-number, if true, cd to this folder. If false, make new customer.

i.e. 1) folder *15112101 Doe* exists in /company/myprogram

start program > asks customer-number > insert *15112101* > output should be:
Customer *15112101 Doe* found, going to /company/myprogram/15112101 Doe

i.e. 2) folder *15112101 Doe* does not exist in /company/myprogram

start program > asks customer-number > insert *15112101* > output should be: Customer does not exist, create new?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`${string}*`  is the directory name beginning with `$string`)

```
if [[ ! $(find . -type d -name ${string}*) ]]; then
 echo "No such customer"
else 
 cd "$string"
```

EDIT:
Fix

**1** `fi` missing

```
if [[ ! $(find . -type d -name ${string}*) ]]; then
  echo "Customer does not exist, create new?"
 else 
  cd $string
 fi
```

**2** in `${string}*` the asterisk needs to be escaped

```
if [[ ! $(find . -type d -name ${string}\*) ]]; then
 echo "Customer does not exist, create new?"
else 
 cd $string
fi
```

**3** if there's more than one directory starting with `$string`, the command `cd $string` doesn't make sense, you need to decide what to do in that case

```
if [[ ! $(find . -type d -name ${string}\*) ]]; then
 echo "Customer does not exist, create new?"
else 
 echo "found customers " $(ls ${string}*);
fi
```

**4** if you have nested directories and you want to exclude them from your search, you need to use `-maxdepth 1`

```
if [[ ! $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name ${string}\*) ]]; then
 echo "Customer does not exist, create new?"
else 
 echo "found customers " $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name ${string}\*);
fi
```

**5** remove double `find`

```
cust=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name ${string}\*)
if [[ ! $cust ]]; then
 echo "Customer does not exist, create new?"
else 
 echo "found customers " $cust;
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, this works!
Only thing that I still need help with is the cd "$string" part.
If the folder is called 15112101 Doe, it means the value of $string is 15112101 (which isn't the foldername I need to go to.. I need 15112101 Doe)

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it by making your line into a variable and then cd'ing to said variable. Thanks again!

Comment: Aside from the fact that `${string}*` needs to be quoted, this will break if there is more than one directory starting with `$string`, or if the only directory found contains whitespace.

Comment: Your `if` statement is missing its closing `fi`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with user2314737's answer:

1. It doesn't take in account if there's a directory with that prefix in a subdirectory. Find should be set a `-depth 1` to omit them.
2. It doesn't take in account the case in which there is more than one directory with that prefix. The question does not specify if this case is possible but it should be considered.
3. No need to use `[[` and `[` is more portable.
4. The final `cd` in the case when the directory is found is performed without a glob at the end `*`. This will fail because `$string` is a prefix, not the complete name of the directory.

Fixing the issues mentioned I present the following solution:

```
PREFIX=123
COUNT=`find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "${PREFIX}*" | wc -l`
if [ $COUNT = "1" ]; then
  echo "There is one and only one directory with prefix $PREFIX"
  cd "${prefix}*"
  pwd
else
  echo "$COUNT directories with prefix $PREFIX"
fi
```

Comment: `-depth 1` is very likely invalid. `-depth` is only a predicate to tell `find` to proceed in a depth-first manner. Will certainly not be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over any and all directories in the folder:

```
shopt -s nullglob
customer_dir=
for d in /company/program/"$string "*/; do
    if [[ -n $customer_dir ]]; then
        echo "Found a second matching dir: $d and $customer_dir"
        # Handle error here
    fi
    customer_dir=$d
done
if [[ -z $customer_dir ]]; then
    echo "No such customer $string; create?"
fi
```

This covers several cases: `nullglob` prevents the loop from being entered if there are no matches, so `customer_dir` never gets set. Ideally, the glob will match either 0 or 1 directory, but to be completely safe, it detects if a second match is found. (What to do in that case, I leave to you.)

Comment: You should quote the expansion `$string` (unless user really wants globs here). Also, is there a reason you don't use `for d in "/company/program/$string"*/; do`?

Comment: True for the first part, and the second I thought of a few minutes after I submitted the answer.